# How to see what data a windows application send through my network?

Tags: networking, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to see what a application send to network and if is possible to edit or stop them. thanks ;)

Comment: 1) You want a packet sniffer. 2) You want to ask that on superuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely recommend [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org).  But be careful, if this is a corporate network you will need permission.  Sniffing traffic can sometimes be cause for instant termination, so get it in writing!

Changing and editing traffic are much more complex tasks.  That answer really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I already have wireshark, but how to see data for a specific application?

Comment: To see data for a specific application, open a cmd window and type `netstat` here you will see all of the applications and what ports they are using (as well as the connections they're connected to and either UDP or TCP). With this information, you should be able to use wireshark to look for packets going over those specific ports and to specific ip addresses.